# Summarizing factor counts by other variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, levels

I'm attempting to summarize the number of observations of levels in a factor variable by other variables in the same dataset. We are running a clinical training study where patients and controls describe pictures, and I'm conducting an analysis of the types of errors patients made. I want to see whether the specific training conditions and session types (baseline, training, post-testing, etc) affect what errors are produced. The data look as follows:

```
| ParticipantID | Group   | SessionType | TrainingCondition | ErrorType |
| p1            | Control | Baseline    | Alternating       | GE        |
| p1            | Control | Baseline    | Alternating       | RR        |
| p1            | Control | Post-Test   | Alternating       | NT        |
...
| p2            | Patient | Baseline    | Single            | GE        |
```

There are three levels of the `SessionType` variable (Baseline, Immediate Post, 1 Week Post), two of the `TrainingCondition` variable (Alternating & Single), and 5 of the `ErrorType` variable (GE, NS, LE, NT, RR). What I need is a summary of how often each level of `ErrorType` occurred by `Group`, `SessionType`, and `TrainingCondition`. Ideally, I'd get something like this:

```
| Group   | SessionType | TrainingCondition | ErrorType | Count |
| Control | Baseline    | Alternating       | GE        | 5     |
| Control | Post-test   | Alternating       | GE        | 10    |
...
| Patient | Baseline    | Single            | NT        | 7     |
&c.
```

I've tried several possible solutions, but none have resulted in what I want. The closest is this code using the `tidyverse`:

```
error.sum <- df %>% 
  group_by(trainingCondition, Group, SessionType, ErrorType) %>%
  summarise(Count = count(df, ErrorType)$n)`
```

Which resulted in something close, but not there. All counts have been duplicated in the output:

```
Alternating | Control | Baseline | GE | 596  |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | GE | 46   |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | GE | 79   |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | GE | 187  |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | GE | 500  |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | GE | 1853 |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | GE | 37   |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | NT | 596  |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | NT | 46   |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | NT | 79   |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | NT | 187  |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | NT | 500  |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | NT | 1853 |
Alternating | Control | Baseline | NT | 37   |
```

I suspect `count()` counted the *overall* instances of each error type rather than counts of `ErrorType` by the other variables? I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `df %>% 
  count(trainingCondition, Group, SessionType, ErrorType, name = "Count")`.

Comment: Inside summarize, you can use `n()` for the number of rows within a group, so `df %>%  group_by(trainingCondition, Group, SessionType, ErrorType) %>% summarise(Count = n())`. However, this is such a common operation that `count` is intended a helper function to make it easier as stefan illustrates. Also, if you take a look at the `?count` help page, the first line say that *"`df %>% count(a, b)` is roughly equivalent to `df %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarise(n = n())`.*

Comment: Thank you both so much for your replies. This solution works brilliantly! I had no idea about `count()` including more extensive functionality like this.